# Schemes whose ring of global sections separate points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a scheme over an algebraically closed field. We say that $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ separates points iff for every $x,y \in X$ there's an $f \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ with $f(x)\ne f(y)$.

This is true for affine schemes. Beyond that it seems a very restrictive property. Does it have any interesting uses? Is there an alternative charactrization for such schemes?

Comment: What exactly would equality $f(x) = f(y)$ mean here?

Comment: @Hoot Consider the scheme as a scheme over $Spec \mathbb{Z}$ take the residue of the stalks to get elements of some field. Equality holds if both fields are extension of the same ground field and the elements $f(x), f(y)$ in these fields are the equal (i.e. both images of an element in some common ground field). If that doesn't work consider only schemes over algebraically closed fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The definition: danger ahead!**
The global functions of a scheme $X$ are said to separate points if, given two points of $ X$, there is a function $f\in \Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X)$ which is zero at one of them and non-zero at the other.
Beware that we may **NOT** choose the one at which it is zero: for example if $X$ is an integral scheme with generic point $x$, any function zero at $x$ will vanish at all other points and in particular at $y$. However it is still possible for a function to be zero at $y$ and non-zero at $x$.
(Recall that $f$ is zero at $z$ if $f[z]=f_z\operatorname {mod} \mathfrak m _z =0\in \mathcal O_{X,z}/\mathfrak m_z$ .  See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1581080/3217))

**Quasi-affine schemes**
A vast supply of  schemes whose global regular functions separate points is provided by the quasi-affine schemes: those are the open subsets of affine schemes.
Here is a **criterion** for a scheme $X$ to be quasi-affine :
 $$ \text {The scheme} \:X \: \text  {is quasi-affine} \\ \iff\\ \operatorname {The canonical scheme morphism} j: X\to \operatorname {Spec} (\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X)) \operatorname {is an open embedding} $$ **A notorious example:**
The scheme $\mathbb A^2\setminus \{O\}$ is quasi-affine but [not affine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/122826/3217).
**A close analogy**
In complex analysis, spaces whose global functions separate points are called holomorphically separable. They are an important ingredient in characterizing Stein spaces.
I'm not aware that there is a similar terminology in algebraic geometry: I find this regrettable [the lack of terminology or my ignorance of it :-)]
 **Their exact opposite**
Complete connected varieties $X$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ (for example projective varieties) have the property that  $\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X)=k$.
 So as soon as they are positive dimensional two points cannot be separated by global functions (but they can be separated by sections of appropriate  line bundles) .
**What are they  good for?**
Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1599532/3217): a quasi-affine variety is confronted to a complete variety to prove that two varieties must intersect in projective space.
**What else is there?**
A paraphrase of the definition at the beginning is: $X$ is quasi-affine iff  the canonical scheme morphism $j: X\to \operatorname {Spec} (\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X))$ is injective.
This is quite close to the criterion above for $X$ to be quasi-affine, so that my intuition is: quasi-affine schemes constitute the "majority" of schemes whose global functions separate points.

Comment: Once again, thank you! Knowing that general statement on "Complete connected varieties" is very comforting.

Comment: Once again, it was my pleasure, Saal ! (Also, I have expanded my answer a little)